# How to make 4 bytes using bit field struct and union?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unions, bit-fields

Here is the code.

```
struct test {
    struct abc {
        int a : 24;
        union b {
            int b1 : 10;
            int b2 : 14;
        };
    };
    int c : 8;
};
```

I want to make the structure abc a 3 byte size, plus an additional 1 byte size variable to make a 4 byte structure. However, sincee the inner structure actually appears as 4 bytes and the total size of structure test is 5 bytes.

I am using the Visual Studio 2017 version. (and I also already used packed option)

How can I size the structure to 4 bytes? This is a bug found in code that is already in use, so dependencies are so large that I can not change the order of variables or create new structures inside.

Comment: sizeof `test`: 4

Comment: there's no point making a structure of 5 bytes, you'll lose on padding to 4 or 8, depending on the compiler flags.

Comment: and yeah, you have `b1` and `b2` overlapping because of the `union`, occupying same 14 bits.

Comment: It is not possible union 2 bytes minimum plus 3 bytes field `a`

Comment: `int c : 8;` is 4 bytes (I'm assuming on your platform sizeof(int) is 4).  The implicit `int : 24` remainder still exists even though omitted explicitly.  Binghe Zhai's answer works because a `byte` is 8 bits (could vary depending on platform, again I'm assuming).

Comment: Oh... my mistake... b is not union but structure..

Comment: @EdwardLee I don't think you understand bitfields at all. `int a : 24;` requires 3 bytes, but you seem to want 2 bytes instead. And `int b1 : 10;` and `int b2 : 14;` both require 2 bytes, but you seem to want 1 byte instead. And `int c : 8;` doesn't make sense when the adjacent fields are not also `int`s using bitfields, so if you want just 1 byte then use `char` or `int8_t` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct test {
    struct abc {
        short a;
        union b {
            byte b1;
            byte b2;
        }_b;
    }_abc;
    byte c;
};
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to use `std::(u)int16_t` instead of `short`, since `short` is not *guaranteed* to be 2 bytes (but usually is). And `std::byte` is not available under C++17, so use `unsigned char` or `std::(u)int8_t` on earlier compilers.